# Ruby on Rails 4 API - update devise user

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build an API with rails 4. Everything(show/delete/create) works fine, but update gives me an error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in
>   Api::V1::UsersController#update

My update method is like this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @user.nil?  
  logger.info("User not found.")
  render :status => 404, :json => {:status => "error", :errorcode => "11009", :message => "Invalid userid."}
  else
    @user.update(params)
    render :status => 200, :json => {:status => "success", :user => @user, :message => "The user has been updated"}
  end
end
```

I send my post request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/3` and I'm sending username:Testuser via PATCH - That should be right for rails 4.

I guess I'm forgetting to allow the paramets to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply forgot the syntax in rails 4.
I just needed to replace `@user.update(params)` 
with  `@user.update_attributes(params.permit(:email, :username, :password))`